# Is this proof that $0^0=1$ valid?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

\begin{align}x^x&=1\\
\ln(x^x)&=\ln(1)\\
x\ln(x)&=0\\
x&=0\\
\therefore0^0&=1\end{align}
Is this valid? Also I care for complex numbers.

Comment: No as $ln(0)$ is undefined. $0^0$ is an indeterminate form meaning that the many functions that approach the form $0^0$ in a limit approach different values.

Comment: For real $x>0,$ no matter how small, $0^x = 0$  but $x^0 = 1.$  So, what would you like to happen for $0^0?$

Comment: How do you begin with $x^x=1$?

Comment: You cannot prove the result but there are reasons to define it as $1$. For example, the number of functions from a set of size $a$ to a set of size $b$, is  $b^a$. Since there is exactly one function from the empty set to the empty set and the size of the empty set is zero, we sometimes define $0^0=1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Correct. $x^0$ is an empty product, and therefore $1$, regardless of what $x$ is. Limits are a red herring. $0^0 = 1$ is a fact that can be established through combinatorics alone.

Comment: @user76284 No. It is not a fact, otherwise it could be proved. It is defined to be one because there are reasons to do so, including the .reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @JohnDouma It *can* be proved though, precisely as you described (or the fact that 1 is the identity element under multiplication).

Answer (score 7):

Consider these two examples:

- $x^0 = 1$ for any $x \neq 0$.
- $0^x = 0$ for any $x > 0$.

Therefore, either the $0^0 \equiv 0$ or $0^0 \equiv 1$ convention is reasonable depending on context.

As @EzTheBoss points out, it depends on how you approach $0^0$.

Comment: I have never seen a situation where $0^0 = 0$ makes sense. On the other hand, $0^0 = 1$ always makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer your title question: Is this proof valid?

No, it is not.

On line 1 of your proof, you are making an implicit assumption, namely that $x$ is an element of the domain of the function $x^x$.

That domain is $(0,\infty)$.

So you are making an implicit assumption that $x > 0$.

With that in mind, your 2nd and 3rd lines are okay.

But the jump to your 4th line is invalid. The correct statement to apply is this: $ab=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$. So line 4 should be should be:
$$x = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad \ln(x)=0
$$
But $x=0$ *contradicts* the implicit assumption that $x>0$. So the only possibility is $\ln(x)=0$, leading to the conclusion that $x=1$.

Comment: but $x\in\Bbb{Z}_-$ too?